# Create group of ip ranges for network security groups in Azure?

Tags: networking, firewall, azure

Is there a way for to group several ip address ranges in Azure?

Usage example: I have a list of IP ranges from Salesforce that I want to whitelist for a bunch of NetworkSecurityGroups. Let's say they add one range. I don't want to go into all of them and add the rule. Is there a mechanism to group these kind of ip ranges?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I test in my lab. Maybe you could use NSG to achieve your scenario. **Azure NSG support IP ranges**. You could configure NSG rules in Azure Portal like below:
[image]

For my test, IP ranges 167.220.250.0/24 could access to my VM, other IP ranges could not access to it.
More information about NSG please refer to the [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal)

Comment: I'm aware that you can define a single range per rule but I have a *list* of ip ranges. In the given example in the question, Salesforce actually has 9 different IP ranges from which it operates. So for each security group you have to create 9 different rules. When they would remove or add one range I have to change the ruleset for every group. I would love to be able to only manipulate that list of ip ranges in one place and refer to it.

Comment: For now, Azure does not support your scenario. Maybe you could try to create 9 rules by using PowerShell cmdlet.  $rule1 = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name frontend-rule `
 -Description "Allow FE subnet" `
 -Access Allow -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 100 `
 -SourceAddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24 -SourcePortRange * `
 -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange *

Answer (score 0):

For what you are looking to do, I would recommend adding **Azure Firewall** protection to compliment your NSG's.  Azure Firewall support policies that would allow you to group rules and only make a change once to the policy.

The Azure Firewall service complements network security group functionality. Together, they provide better "*defense-in-depth*" network security. Network security groups provide distributed network layer traffic filtering to limit traffic to resources within virtual networks in each subscription. Azure Firewall is a fully stateful, centralized network firewall as-a-service, which provides network- and application-level protection across different subscriptions and virtual networks.

[image]